# variable defined as type never after null check

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using TypeScript, I have an optional state parameter on a React component that gives me the following error even after a null check:

> Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'.

Why is `items` inferred as type `never` even after returning when `!items`?

```
interface TestProps {
  someProp: string;
}

interface TestState {
  items?: { id: string; name: string; }[];
}

class Test extends Component<TestProps, TestState> {
  state = {
    items: undefined,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { items } = this.state;

    // in my scenario, if !items, then run some logic
    // that will get the items and setState to those items
    // so even though initial state = { items: undefined }
    // it will be set eventually by the api call.
    // perhaps this isn't a good pattern for the compiler?
    if (!items) fetchItemsFromApi();

  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;

    if (!items) {
      return <div>Nothing to show</div>;
    }

    return items && items.length ? (
      <div>There's {items.length} items</div>
    ) : (
      <div>There are no items</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after thinking of this some more and [reading about the `never` type](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/never.html), I realized that initializing the state property to undefined caused the compiler to infer that `items` was undefined, therefore, deemed the code after the null check to be unreachable.

By adding the `TestState` annotation onto the class `state` property and not setting the `items` property on `state` I no longer get the error and `items` is inferred as type `{ id: string; name: string; }[]` after the null check as expected.

```
class Test extends Component<TestProps, TestState> {
  state: TestState = {
  };

  // ...the rest of the class
}
```